# Get link from xml-file with regex

Tags: android, xml, regex

I want to get this link from a xml-file, is that possible with regex?

```
<src>
rtmp://cp8619.edgefcs.net/416x234_93912.mp4
</src>
```

I tried something like this `Pattern.compile("(rtmp[[a-z][0-9]]{39})");` but i'm always getting the following error in this line:

```
p_quality.matcher(xml_code_stored_in_a_string);

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.lang.CharSequence.length()' on a null object reference
```

I'm using a similar pattern to get a "video-id" from html-code and it's working there, but it's not working with this xml-code.

Comment: Why don't you use an XML parser?

Comment: @Philio to parse the xml, he needs (should use) a xml parser for sure. but to extract the link from that string, xml parser won't help.

Comment: @Philio wait, I read his question twice, I thought you are right... he wanted to have the complete rtmp: link.... not extract part from that link. sry..

Comment: It seems you'll get that issue due to not looking for extra characters such as ":/.". What about "(rtmp.*)?\<\/"? since you know it would end with a "</" which you don't wish to capture

Comment: So, managed to get this to work. Turns out that the string where i store the xml-code was actually empty. Thats why I got that error. But it's working now! And this is the pattern i'm using for the regex-thingie: `(rtmp.*)(mp4)`. Pretty simple and returns the full link.

Comment: @f4bzen Just remember that regular expressions are greedy... so if you have multiple `src` blocks (or even multiple things having `rtmp` or `mp4`) then you will capture everything in between. Your rule is "find `rtmp` and then as much as you possibly can and then the string `mp4`... You can make it non-greedy using `rtmp.*?mp4` (but if there is mp4 in the link before the end this will stop short) - perhaps `rtmp://.*?\.mp4` would be more accurate. Note that you don't need the `()` as that just tells it to capture the group - you are just matching so don't need groups like that